# C# exception Could not load file or assembly xxx or one of its dependencies. The media is write protected

Tags: c#, .net

It is a console application running on windows server. Sometimes it throws out this error while reading data from database into dataset.

```
adapter.Fill(dataset, "users")
```

Most of the time, the code is runing fine in server. Ocasionally, it throws out this error, but very soon it recovers. I guess it is something related with windows system while loading assembly. Somethime it throws out while loading `System.Xml`, sometimes it throws out while loading `System.Web`.
Here is stack trace.

```
Exception : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The media is write protected. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070013)   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.IsProviderSpecificNullValue(Object value)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.SetStatus(Int32 arraySize)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
```

Or

```
Exception : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The media is write protected. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070013)
```

Any clue why it happens?

Comment: Version 2.0. Damn, are you running Framework 3.5.1? Every other "recent" framework uses 4.0 (recent used loosely here, v2.0 came out in 2005, 3.5.1 came out in 2008 or 2010)

Comment: From Visual Studio, I see its target framework is 4.0

Comment: Hum, the references is also 4.0.0.0, from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll

Comment: What version of the database software and what version of the client are you using? The versions should match (or at least be close).

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid, yes, they are match. Otherwise, the console application cannot run. This exception only happens very occasinally.

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/InstallODP.html#GUID-5487F4DD-69BB-4FF2-9FD6-5512EDA14F31,  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/featCodeAccess.html#GUID-35586B6E-4D5B-42A8-ACF1-F9FEFD90BCFD, and https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/InstallConfig.html#GUID-1F689B90-2CC4-4907-B8FE-A5F4EE36F673

Comment: Thanks @Tudeschizieuinchid. I have kind of feeling that it is not related with Oracle. It also has this exception in somewhere else while loading other assembly.

Comment: The big gun for this kind of issue is the _Fusion Log Viewer_. Read up on [FusLogVw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer).exe